# Database design - a many-to-many table which links the same entities?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table **User** with a column **id**. I want the user to have relationships with other users, so I create a table **Relationships** with columns **user_id_1** and **user_id_2**.

The questions is how to constrain the table so that

1) there are no entries where **user_id_1** equals **user_id_2**.

For example, entry (1, 1) is bad, because it indicates a relationship to oneself.

2) if there is an entry **(user_id_1, user_id_2)**, the entry **(user_id_2, user_id_1)** is not allowed.

For example, having entries (1, 2) and (2, 1) is bad, because it indicates the same relationship.

I am using MySQL, although I think this is a general design issue. Thanks!

Comment: The problem will be solved differently on different databases, depending on features (for example, MySql doesn't have CHECK constraints).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a `INSERT` and `UPDATE` [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) on the join table that check these conditions.

Comment: I think I'll go with this approach, and Johan's code is a good base. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You use a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER bi_relationschip_each BEFORE INSERT ON relationship FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.user1_id = NEW.user2_id THEN
    SELECT error_user1_cannot_be_equal_to_user2 FROM generate_error;
  END IF; 
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```